# morrisJS Bar chart population using PHP and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, morris.js

I'm struggling with getting data to populate my MorrisJS bar chart using data from my mySQL database. Could anyone assist in getting it to display on my bar chart?

Below is my current code and pages.

```
    <?php
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('database') or die('Could not select database');

$dataArray=array();

//get data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $Version=$row["Version"];
      $Live=$row["Live"];
      $Preprod=$row["Preprod"];
      //add to data areray
      $dataArray[$Version]=$count;
  }
}
?>
```

index.php (main page)

```
div id="morris-bar-chart"></div>
  <?php include ('database.php') ?>

<script src="../js/morris-data.js"></script> <----- script on index.php page linking to morris chart page.
```

morris.js page

```
 Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: [{


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        y:<?=$row['versions']?>,
        Live:<?=$row['Live']?>,
        PreProd: <?=$row['Preprod']?>
    }, {

          ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['Live', 'PreProd'],
    labels: ['Live', 'PreProd'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

Hope this all makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the while is the problem.

Morris expects data line-wise, e.g. `{ y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },`

I've adjusted the PHP code part in the `morris.js` script a bit.

- Normally, you can not execute PHP within a JS file. Except, when you added a rule to the server, that JS files should be processed by PHP, too.
- The normal way to fetch the data would be an AJAX query to a PHP script, which returns the `json_encoded($result)`. And then add it to Morris with the `setData()` function.
- But this should work, too: generate the JS file by PHP. You could rename the `morris-data.js` to `morris-data.js.php`. The file needs `<?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>` at the top. And then adjust your `<script` include to match the new filename.

File `morris-data.js.php`

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>

Morris.Bar({
  element: 'morris-bar-chart',
  data: [        
  <?php 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        // output a line like:
        // { y: '123', Live: 123,  PreProd: 123 },
        sprintf(
            "{ y: '%s', Live: %s, PreProd: %s },",
            $row['version'], 
            $row['Live'],
            $row['Preprod']
        );
      } 
  ?>
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['Live', 'PreProd'],
  labels: ['Live', 'PreProd'],
  hideHover: 'auto',
  resize: true
});
```

that should render something like (see also the [bar chart example](http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?js,output))

```
data: [       
    { y: '1.2.3', Live: 20,  PreProd: 23 },
    { y: '1.2.4', Live: 30,  PreProd: 24 },
    { y: '1.2.5', Live: 40,  PreProd: 25 },
    { y: '1.2.6', Live: 50,  PreProd: 26 }
],
```

(I'm not sure what the last part in the `database.php` file is supposed to do.
Maybe you can drop that (the code inside the `if($result)`). But maybe its for calculations..)

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion keep can't pass my mysql data to the chart. As far as I understand the code that you have provided should work. I'm guessing it could be the sql that is causing the problem. Have you got anymore ideas?  Thanks again

Comment: Hi Matthew, the SQL seems pretty basic here. Just a connect and a fetch-all query from the table. You could add a `var_dump()` to check that you have a `$result` after (`$result = mysql_query(..)`). -- You could also copy the row output loop (while row sprintf) and position it directly after the mysq_query() - to test content generation and debug problems with MySQL. -- I still think the PHP is not executed inside JS. Did you try to rename the JS file to `morris-data.js.php`?

Comment: Yeah I tried to rename the file but then the graph is disappearing from the screen. Which to me means that the index page can't find the page... I'll give the var_dump a go